# Running own OpenLS using OpenStreetMap data

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding-service

I'm looking to create my own geocoding service for a client.
The web application will run on intranet and won't have access to the internet.

Is there a way I can run OpenLS like service of geocoding using OSM data?

The map will be displayed with OL + Geoserver and OSM shp file.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem, just started my research and still haven't found an answer, **but**:

1. there has been a recent post to the geoserver-dev list regarding an
   ongoing [GeoServer OpenLS services implementation](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/GeoServer-OpenLS-services-implementation-td5027381.html)
2. the [OpenRouteService](http://www.openrouteservice.org/contact.php) states that *"soon we will also make the
   route service available as OGC-web service, that can be used through
   http-based xml-requestes as specified in the OGC OpenLS Route
   Service specification. This will allow developers to use this
   servide in an open and interoperable way easily within their own
   applications."* However, source code doesn't seem to be publicly available.
3. the OpenLayers OpenLS example (at the OpenLayers site) is using the above mentioned OpenRouteService.
4. if OpenLS compliance is not a strict requirement, you might use **Nominatim**.

Anyhow, in either case I don't think you'll be able to use an OSM *shapefile* to support your service: a PostgreSQL+PostGIS+pgRouting database will most certainly be required.